# Lighttpd proxy to hostname

Tags: proxy, webserver, subdomain, lighttpd, host

I need proxy connections on server side with Lighttpd from `https://example.org/xxx/id` to `http://sub.example.org:1234/xxx/id`.

How can I make this with mod_proxy?

I need somethng like this:

```
"/xxx" => (
 ( "host" => "sub.example.org", "port" => 1234 )
)
```

but

> "host": is ip of the proxy server DO not use hostnames here! only IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.46 (released in 2017) will use DNS to resolve the host to an IP address at lighttpd startup.  If multiple IP addresses are returned, only the first IP is used.